# How to check if even one div is expanded or all closed?

Tags: jquery

I have three expandable div, and i need condition to check if even one of them is open but i dont know how or check if all of them closed. Any help?

http://jsfiddle.net/sutekh/ku8B9/

```
$("#expand dt a").click(function () {
   $(this).parent().siblings("dd").slideToggle(); 
});
```

Comment: Will http://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/Lswfo88e/2/ help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to know if you have any other expanded divs you can use `:visible` selector

```
$("#expand dt a").click(function () {
    if( $('#expand dd:visible').length > 0) {
    alert('you already have opened ' +  $('#expand dd:visible').length + ' question(s)');
  }
   $(this).parent().siblings("dd").slideToggle(); 
});
```

will cause the alert to popup if you will try to expand two or more divs at the same time.
Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ku8B9/250/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this output:

http://jsfiddle.net/ku8B9/249/

```
$("#expand dt a").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings("dd").slideToggle();
  var index = $(this).closest("dl").index() + 1;
  if (index % 2 == 0)
    alert("even question");
  else
    alert("odd question");
});
```